# Nested Case Expression to parse out the CLINICAL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the following code:

```
USE EMTCQIData

SELECT FIN, Clinical, FCT_MAX, FCT_MAX_CHARGES, CPT, CPT_CHARGES
    , (FCT_MAX_CHARGES - CPT_CHARGES) AS DELTA
FROM (
    SELECT CONC.[Financial Number] as FIN, CONC.Clinical
        , CASE
        WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 5%' THEN '99285' 
        WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 4%' THEN '99284'
        END FCT_MAX
        , CASE
        WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 5%' THEN CAST($200 AS int) 
        WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 4%' THEN CAST($100 AS int)
        END FCT_MAX_CHARGES
        , CPT.CPT
        , CASE
        WHEN CPT.CPT like '99285' THEN CAST($200 AS int) 
        WHEN CPT.CPT like '99284' THEN CAST ($100 AS int)
        END CPT_CHARGES
    FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[Financial Number] 
            , SUBSTRING((
                SELECT ',' + ST1.[Clinical Event Result] AS [text()]
                FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 ST1
                WHERE ST1.[Financial Number] = ST2.[Financial Number]
                AND ST1.[Clinical Event Result] <> 'No'
                ORDER BY [Financial Number] 
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 2, 1000) [Clinical]
        FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 ST2
    ) AS CONC ON CONC.[Financial Number] = CPT.FIN
    WHERE CPT.CPT LIKE '9928%'
) AS COMPLETE
ORDER BY FIN
```

This code produces the following table:

```
FIN   Clinical                              FCT_MAX    FCT_MAX_Charges    CPT   CPT_Charges    DELTA 
1     Discharge[Level1], Transfer[Leve3]        9284       200          9283     100          100
2     Vital[Level1], Triage [Level4]            9284       200          9282     50          150
```

I want to add a nested CASE expression to parse out the CLINICAL column; however I am unsure where to nest the CASE expressions. The CASE expression will transform the table so that a new column is created when there is a certain value withing the CLINICAL column.

The CASE code looks like this:

```
CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Discharge%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Discharge
etc...
```

I would like the final desired results to look like this:

```
FIN   Discharge  Transfer  Triage  Vital   FCT_MAX    FCT_MAX_Charges    CP CPT_Charges    DELTA 
1      1          1         0       0          9284       200           9283     100          100
2      0          0         1       1          9284       200           9282     50          150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE EMTCQIData

SELECT FIN
  --, Clinical
  , CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Discharge%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Discharge
  , CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Transfer%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Transfer
  , CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Triage%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Triage
  , CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Vital%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Vital
  , FCT_MAX, FCT_MAX_CHARGES, CPT, CPT_CHARGES, 
(FCT_MAX_CHARGES - CPT_CHARGES) AS DELTA

FROM
(
SELECT CONC.[Financial Number] as FIN, CONC.Clinical, 

CASE
      WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 5%' THEN '99285' 
      WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 4%' THEN '99284'
END FCT_MAX,

CASE
      WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 5%' THEN CAST($200 AS int) 
      WHEN CONC.Clinical like '%level 4%' THEN CAST($100 AS int)
END FCT_MAX_CHARGES,

CPT.CPT,

CASE
      WHEN CPT.CPT like '99285' THEN CAST($200 AS int) 
      WHEN CPT.CPT like '99284' THEN CAST ($100 AS int)
END CPT_CHARGES

FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT

INNER JOIN 

 (
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.[Financial Number], 
SUBSTRING(
(
    SELECT ','+ST1.[Clinical Event Result]  AS [text()]
    FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 ST1
    WHERE ST1.[Financial Number] = ST2.[Financial Number] AND ST1. 
 [Clinical Event Result]<> 'No'
          Order BY [Financial Number] 
    FOR XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) [Clinical]
 FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19 ST2
)
as CONC ON CONC.[Financial Number]=CPT.FIN
WHERE CPT.CPT LIKE '9928%'
)
AS COMPLETE

ORDER BY FIN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggravated function `SUM` with `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT FIN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Discharge%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Discharge,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Transfer%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Transfer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Triage%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Triage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Clinical LIKE '%Vital%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Vital,
    FCT_MAX,
    FCT_MAX_Charges,
    CPT,
    CPT_Charges 
FROM T
GROUP BY 
    FIN,
    FCT_MAX,
    FCT_MAX_Charges,
    CPT,
    CPT_Charges
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f5806f89d208f6838ea07b18317a2ad)

**NOTE**

use your subquery you currently using to instead `T`.